# why am I getting a ForbiddenAttributesError when using protected_attributes gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

We just upgraded to rails 4.1.13 from 4.0.1. We've dragged our feet at implementing strong parameters. As such, we are still using the `protected_attributes` gem so we can use the old behavior.

Now, we are getting an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`. I do not understand why, since we are using the `protected_attributes` gem..

Comment: `protected_attributes` gem, as far as I remember, requires you to add `attr_accessible` for any attribute which will be mass assigned in your application. If you triies to assign an attribute which is not marked as accessible, you'll get this error. It is completely redundant if you have strong params in place, as it will requre you permit each attribute twice, once in the controller and once in the model.

Comment: that does actually fix it. But how odd that it worked under 4.0.1 without it..

Comment: I believe Rails 4.01 just issued a warning so that developers had a bit of time to implement strong parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use the following code snippet to mark attributes safe for mass assignment other than the id attribute of your model

```
attr_protected :id
```

Please note that doing so makes all the attributes other than id of your model safe for mass assignment.
If most of the attributes of your model can be mass assigned, I think using `attr_protected` instead of using `attr_accessible` makes more sense as it does the same job without writing more lines of code.