# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ArtsController#create in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting this error: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in ArtsController#create` I understand that this means I need to permit items to pass, which I have done, but I must be missing something.

My Arts controller

```
private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_art
        @art = Art.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def art_params
        params.require(:art).permit(:name, :status, :theme, :uni, :duration, :semester_duration)
      end
```

Art model

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

I am using rails 4 in windows pc. I followed rails 4 whitelist params but still get this error. Please help me to find what I am missing here.

Comment: This should work. The code looks fine. Try to reload the server. If it will not help, show the request log.

Comment: Are all of these values columns in your art table or are you using virtual attributes and other table columns?

Comment: These are the columns of my table. ["id", "name", "status", "created_at", "updated_at", "theme", "uni", "duration", "semester_duration"]. I am not using any other table or virtual tables. Also I tried restart the server as well.

Comment: Show your Gemfile file

Comment: added. BTW, I just upgraded my project from rails 3.2 to rails 4 and ruby 1.9.3 to 2.1.5. Also I was using gem 'protected_attributes' and it was working just fine. But now I moved my params in controller and commented out the gem and I started to get this error for all other models also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is similar to this one [why am I getting a ForbiddenAttributesError when using protected_attributes gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599112/why-am-i-getting-a-forbiddenattributeserror-when-using-protected-attributes-gem)

The problem is related to the protected_attributes gem, that requires permitted attributes to be added to attr_accessible block in a model.

But, since you are not using this gem anymore, the exact reason of the problem is unknown.

Maybe some of your old gems still require `attr_accessible`.

Are you using `cancan` ? Try to remove it from your Gemfile. If you need `cancan`, use `cancancan` instead.

Comment: Thanks mate. You just saved my day. Changing gem from cancan to cancancan solved the problem.

Comment: The `CanCan` maintainer had a burnout just before the Rails 4 strong params showed up so it was never really implemented in the original. Long story short - the community forked cancan - so it lives on through CanCanCan.

Comment: Please, just to make your question clearer, return back the log of the request. Only the part of it which shows parameters which are sent, the error log is not needed.  And the Gemfile file too, please.